# how to do a loop for callbacks (C++)

Tags: c++, plugins, callback

I am trying to do a plugin like:

```
main process()
{
   call plugin to do something;
}

plugin()
{
   PART A: to encode a message, and send to other app;
   PART B: to decode a message, and call PART A to check whether we need to send more messages.
}
```

So, for PART B, it will be called automatically, when the reply returns. When I am in PARTB, I will return to PART A, but I am in PART A, I can't directly call PART B, because it should be called when a reply returns, so how can I do a loop in async call? When I send a message, how to wait until the reply comes to PART B. Thanks for your suggesion.

Comment: Looks like your plugin needs to be some kind of object not a function. objects can of course have more than one method and can hold state.

You call one method asynchronously which leads to the other being called? Should be easy enough with an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is up to your implementation of main process and design of your plugins for example I have something like this:

```
struct message;
typedef std::function<bool(message&)> message_handler;
struct IMainProcess {
    virtual int add_listener( message_handler const& f ) = 0;
    virtual void remove_listener( int key ) = 0;
};
struct IPlugin {
    virtual bool initialize( IMainProcess* p ) = 0;
    virtual void shutdown() = 0;
};

struct MainProcess : IMainProcess {
    int key;
    std::map<int, message_handler > listeners;
    MainProcess() : key( 0 ) {}
    virtual int add_listener( message_handler const& f ) {
        int res = key++;
        listeners[key] = f;
    }
    virtual void remove_listener( int key ) {
        listeners.erase( key );
    }

    void message_received( message& m ) {
        // call all plugins that registered for incoming messages
        for( auto i = listeners.begin(); i != listeners.end(); i++ ) {
            if( !i->second(m) ) break;
        }
    }
};
int main() {
    MainProcess mp;
    // Load plugins from some location and initialize them
    std::vector<std::auto_ptr<IPlugin> > plugins;
    while( IPlugin* p = load_plugin() ) {
        std::auto_ptr<IPlugin> sp( p );
        if( p->initialize(&mp) ) plugins.push_back( sp );
    }
    while( message* msg = wait_for_message() ) {
        std::auto_ptr<message> smsg( msg );
        mp.message_received( *msg );
    }
    // end of operation
    for( auto i = plugins.begin(); i != plugins.end(); i++ ) {
        (*i)->shutdown();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now plugin can have any desired architecture and can also receive incoming messages!